# Failed to download package - NuGet Packages - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I've got this error in my Xamarin Forms project for all the packages installed in it:

Failed to download package 'Fody.6.5.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fody/6.5.1/fody.6.5.1.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET [https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fody/6.5.1/fody.6.5.1.nupkg'](https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fody/6.5.1/fody.6.5.1.nupkg%27) has timed out after 100000ms.

I've cleaned the solution & restoring NuGet Package but I still have the same errors.

Comment: Seems like a network issue. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install older versions.May be related to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to restart VS to get the package to reinstall.And just to confirm, make sure your internet connection active and stable at the time.Also,you can try to install other versions of Fody as Furkan mentioned.